# googleapis.com/youtube/v3 works in browser, but not curl

Tags: curl, youtube-data-api

curl -s https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCIVY11504PcY2sy2qpRhiMg&type=video&eventType=live&key=[MyRealAPIKey]

returns the dreaded:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

The API key and query are good, because if I copy/paste that URL (with my real key) into Safari, FF, or Chrome on OS X or Windows, I get results. I even logged out of my accounts in the browsers to ensure it wasn't a login issue.

But if I attempt curl from the console, it fails. I've copy/pasted both ways, from terminal to browser and from browser to terminal, so I know I'm not making a typo.

BTW, the ultimate goal is write some sort of shell script to check this every 5 minutes and alert me if my stream has gone offline, so if there's a better way to do that, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please try again after it encloses the URL using double or single quotations. When it is not used, the URL is separated by `&` and used as several commands. So such error occurs.

```
curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCIVY11504PcY2sy2qpRhiMg&type=video&eventType=live&key=[MyRealAPIKey]"
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please confirm whether "YouTube Data API v3" is enabled again.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: You are wise! Thank you!

Comment: @Steven Kan Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.